how to initiate an public undeletion vote on my question?
my question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77304/how-to-convert-the-parameters-of-multi-factors-cheyette-model-quasi-gaussian-mo is deleted by community bot as it has not been answered for a long time.
But I believe that the questions I've raised are of great value, and there are no similar questions on the platform. If someone can solve this problem, it will be of great help to many others.
And I had voted to undelete. But two more votes from others are needed to undelete the post.  So how can I get others to see my voting request?

I have undeleted the post.

You may want to edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking. That way, you're more likely to get answers. For example, I'm very sorry, but I simply don't quite understand your question.
